# How to calculate work

Tags: calculus, physics

What is the work done by the force of gravity on a particle of mass $m$ as it moves radially from $7500 ~\text{km}$ to $9400 ~\text{km}$ from the center of the earth?

Comment: What work do you have so far?

Comment: do we use
$\vec{F} =−\frac{GMm\vec{r}}{\left|\,\vec{r}\,\right|^3}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the conservation of energy, the amount of work done by working against gravity is the difference in potential energy. That is, the difference in
$$
-\dfrac{GMm}{r}\tag{1}
$$
between the two points. If we know that
$$
\frac{GM}{r^2}=9.80665 \text{ m/sec}^2\quad\text{at}\quad r=6.371\times10^6\text{ m}\tag{2}
$$
we get that $GM=3.980\times10^{14}\text{ m}^3\text{/sec}^2$. Now just plug $m$, $r$, and $GM$ into $(1)$.

Comment: i got 6.224*10^8 i dont think its correct.

Comment: @MichaelRametta: do you know $m$?

Comment: i dont know m thats why i am confused i already know the equation to use i just dont know how to solve it.

Comment: @MichaelRametta: How did you get an answer without knowing $m$? Without knowing $m$, what I get is
$$
3.980\times10^{14}\text{ m}^3\text{/sec}^2\left(\frac1{7.5\times10^{6}\text{ m}}-\frac1{9.4\times10^{6}\text{ m}}\right)=1.073\times10^7\text{ m}^2\text{/sec}^2
$$
which, when multiplied by $m$ in $\text{kg}$, will give the energy in $\text{J}$ (joules).

Comment: from there i would do?

Comment: I thought everything was spelled out. What is confusing?

Comment: i figured it out thanks

Comment: @MichaelRametta: to get $6.224\times10^8\text{ J}$, $m$ needs to be about $58\text{ kg}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $$W = \int F \cdot dx = \int -\frac{GMm}{r^2} \cdot dr = -GMm\int\frac{1}{r^2} \ dr$$

where $M$ denotes the mass of the Earth and $m$ denotes the mass of the object. Integrate and plug in your bounds for the position.

Comment: what do i do with the given numbers

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Your lower bound and upper bounds on the integral are $7500$ km and $9400$ km. You should know $G, M$ and $m$. Watch your units--I'd convert everything to meters first!

Comment: is it 6.224*10^8 ?